Horror movie where girl can move things with her mind (not "Carrie")
I've been searching forever for this one movie. It's about a girl who can move objects/things with her mind/eyes. It's a horror movie, but it's not Carrie. If I remember correctly, SHE CAN NOT SPEAK. She's mute. It's a fairly old movie, I watched it when I was little. At least more than six years ago, and it's an English movie. I think.
This is the scenes I remember:

Starts with a little girl drawing a happy picture of a house. Then she starts to add big 'stones' to the picture, and what she's drawing is exactly happening in reality (not sure whose house targeted, could be grandparents?)
When she's angry, she makes the cabins' doors open and shut for example. And at one point, when she was really nervous, she stared at a bike, and the wheels started spinning like crazy.
There was a scene when she was lying in bed, with music playing in the background. She then turned her gaze to the music player, and with her mind/eyes shut it off. I think she also opened the CD-drive.
For some reasons, she walks to a house (I think) in the middle of the night. And there's a light there. And if I remember correctly, she holds out her hands to it, to touch it. (I think that was a bad thing).


Matilda.......??

Welcome to Movies & TV. I've closed and deleted your newer version of the question as a duplicate of this one and added the part about being an English movie. If you want to update anything in your question, you can always use the little "edit" link under the question. Also feel free to take a look at the [tour] and the [help] to get a better grip of how this site works.

Starts with a little girl drawing a happy picture of a house... really reminded me of Paperhouse. No telekinesis though.

Rose Red? I remember this autistic type girl who didn't speak but she drew pictures of the neighbors house and then started drawing stones and in real life stones fell out of the sky and crushed the neighbors house.

Paperhouse? I'm having trouble remembering the details, but it was about a little girl who drew a house and visits it. It's from the UK and was released in 1988.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098061 
